# Can an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ be described as the disjoint union of uncountably many open intervals?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

The lecture notes I'm working through pose the question of whether any open set in $\mathbb{R}$ can be described as the disjoint union of uncountably many open intervals.

The problem doesn't state which topology on $\mathbb{R}$ I'm using. I know that any open set can be written as a union of open balls, and an open ball in $\mathbb{R}$ with its usual topology is an open interval, so I assume this is using the standard topology. (If it doesn't matter, I'd be interested in knowing.)

Intuitively, I believe the answer is no, but here's my attempt at a proof. It essentially mimics the argument that any collection of non-overlapping discs in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is countable.

> Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ be open, and $\{G_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in I}$ an uncountable collection of disjoint, open intervals such that $U = \bigcup\limits_{\alpha \in I} G_{\alpha}$. As each $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, in each $G_{\alpha}$, we can choose a rational $q_{\alpha}$. As the $\{G_{\alpha}\}$ are disjoint, if $q_{i}$ lives in $G_i$ for some $i \in I$, then $q_i \not \in G_{\alpha}$ for every $\alpha \neq i$. Therefore, we can write an injection $f: I \to \mathbb{Q}$ sending $\alpha \mapsto q_{\alpha}$. As $f$ is injective, $I \cong f(I) \subset \mathbb{Q}$. As $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable and a subset of a countable set is countable, $f(I)$ is countable, so $I$ is countble, and we have a contradiction.

I'd appreciate some advice on how to improve the proof. I don't think I need contradiction, for example. I could just just take $U$ to be a union of disjoint open intervals -- which may not even exist; at least, I haven't proved that -- and then prove that $I$ must be countable. I also found myself having trouble using appropriate notation to distinguish between the variable $\alpha$ and the specific index $i$.

Comment: You need to have the usual topology, in general this is not true. For example if you take $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete topology then $\mathbb{R}=\cup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} \lbrace x\rbrace$.

Comment: About your proof, this looks good to me. Notice that you definition of $f$ implies the axiom of choice, but I don't think that there is a solution without it.

Comment: @Marcos Yes, I definitely used the axiom of choice. Do I need contradiction, though? This is my main uncertainty at this point. I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: @Marcos Is $\{x\}$ an open interval though?

Comment: No, you dont, I'll add a proof without contradiction in a few minutes, but it is not easier nor sorter, your approach is quite nice.

Comment: Your proof is correct, but you’re proving much more than is needed. As @Randall stated any open interval cannot be written as disjoint union of more than 1 open intervals. What you are proving is basically that there cannot be a family of disjoint open intervals, or even sets. Note that you can rephrase your prove: If $F$ is a family of open, disjoint sets then one can find a function that maps $F$ injectively into $\mathbb Q$, thus $F$ is at most countable.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what the definition of interval is in a non-euclidean space, so for other topologies this does not have much more sense. The result is that every open set of $\mathbb{R}$ can't be written as a non-countable disjoint union of connected open sets (but connected open sets in $(\mathbb{R},\tau_U)$ happens to be intervals).

Comment: I think the phrasing is off.  Maybe "prove *there is no open set* expressible as an disjoint union of uncountably many open intervals."

Answer (score 1):

If $\Bbb R$ has the standard *order*, let $G_i, i \in I$ be a pairwise disjoint family of open intervals , say $G_i = (a_i, b_i)$ with $a_i < b_i$ two reals for each $i \in I$.

For each $i \in I$ we can pick a rational $q_i \in \Bbb Q$ so that $a_i < q_i < b_i$. This has nothing to do with any topology but with the **construction/definition** of $\Bbb R$ from $\Bbb Q$.

It follows that $I \to q_i$ is an injective function from $I$ (by disjointness) into a countable set. Hence $I$ is at most countable.

There simply doesn't exist **any** uncountable disjoint family of open intervals in $\Bbb R$, answering the question independently of any topology you might put on $\Bbb R$...

Comment: Note that if you use another unrelated order, like a well-order, there *can* be such a family.

Comment: What is your definition for interval in a general topology? I don't think that the statement of the problem has sense for an arbitrary topology.

Comment: @Marcos interval has nothing to do with a topology, only with an order. There are no "intervals" in a general space. But $\Bbb R$ *comes* with an order so interval is a defined notion.

Comment: but these are open intervals, so the topology is involved here. For example, in the discrete topology what is defined to be an open interval?

Comment: @Marcos On $\Bbb R$ an open interval is a set of the form $\{x\mid a < x < b\}$ for some $a<b$ in $\Bbb R$. It's called open because it's "open-ended" not because it is open in any topology.

Comment: Well, in that case you're right, but I am not convinced with the fact that an open interval can be non open.

Comment: @Marcos It's open in the standard topology from the metric, but not in the cofinite topology, e.g.

Comment: Yes, I guess you are right. Sorry for the inconvenience. I am not used to work in non standard topologies, so I've never thought that open intervals could be defined in general.

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in a comment you are basically proving that there cannot exist an uncountable family of disjoint open sets (you can easily extend your proof to arbitrary separable spaces). But we can in facht prove this without AOC:

Let F be a family of open disjoint sets.
We define for $q\in\mathbb Q$ the set $F_q = \{O\in F:q\in O\}$. The disjoint property then means that $F_q$ has at most one element. But for each $O\in F$ there exists at least on $q\in O$, so
$$ F = \bigcup_{q\in\mathbb Q} F_q$$
and is thus at most countable.

The trick here is that we do not in fact need any uniqueness of this $q$.

Comment: Areyou sure this doesn't use the AOC? In my oppinion this is equivalent to all other proofs.

Comment: @Marcos Yes, this does not use AOC. The reason why the other versions require the AOC is because they try to find a *single* $q$ for each $O\in F$ to define an injection into $\mathbb Q$, while this does not care about such things and simply defines a surjection *from* $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @Marcos Basically the other proof goes: We take the system of disjoint and nonempty sets defined by $O\cap \mathbb Q$ where $O\in F$ and then find by AOC a system of representatives $q_O$ to define this injection. Here we do the other direction, so for any $q$ we take the set of all $O\in F$ that contain $q$. Then we get that this can contain at most one set simply from the fact that all sets are disjoint.

Comment: @Marcos fix a bijection $h:\Bbb N \to \Bbb Q$ (this can be done explicitly) and define (in my version) $m(i)= \min \{n \in \Bbb N: a_i < h(n) < b_i\}$ (non-empty set so the min exists) and  set $q_i=h(m(i))$. No AC is required at all.

Comment: Thanks, honestly I'm quite suprised that this can be done withouth the AOC. Nice solution!!

Comment: @Marcos We do not really need the AOC in the other case either, to be honest, as we can prove it: If $X$ is countable it also has a well order. Having a well order is equivalent to the AOC, as we can choose our represenatives by the minimum of each set. So assuming that $\mathbb N$ is well-ordered suffices for this proof.

Comment: Only true if we don't have to choose a well-order but can give a bijection with $\Bbb N$ explicitly... There also is the axiom of countable choice which is independent of ZF..

Answer (score 0):

This is the direct proof you want:

Let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ and let us define an equivalence relation:
$$x\sim y\Leftrightarrow\exists I\subset U\text{ open interval such that }x,y\in I$$
This is easily proven to be an equivalence relation and thus we can consider $U/\sim$. In this space, the equivalence classes are given by the open intervals of $U$. If we denote as $I_x$ the open interval containing $x\in U$, let us prove that $|U/\sim|\leq\aleph_0$:

For every $x\in U$ there exists $a_x\in\mathbb{Q}\cap I_x$ (because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$) and $x\nsim y\Rightarrow I_x\cap I_y=\emptyset$. Thus, using the axiom of choice, we can define $\phi:\mathbb{R}/\sim\to\mathbb{Q}$ by $\phi(I_x)=a_x$. Trivially $x\nsim y\Rightarrow \phi(I_x)\neq \phi(I_y)$ and then $|U/\sim|\leq|\mathbb{Q}|\leq\aleph_0$, as we wanted to prove.

Although this is a direct proof the idea is more or less the same as what you did in your contradiction proof.